# How can i know if a hex color is blue?

Tags: php, colors, hex

I would like to know if one hexadecimal code color is in blue range.

I'm using Ghero Dominant color to get it, but I need know if this color is like blue.

```
$color = DominantColor::setColor($sourceimage)->getColor();
```

Anybody know some function or have any array with hex blue colors?

Comment: Would it not be better to check the documentation of the library?

Comment: Can you use [this](https://gist.github.com/rowanmanning/425464/2df6637e2e04b3043755281e0b53e66f35961bb6#file-phpcolor-php-L109) and then check the blue amount and compare it with the R and G?

Comment: Thank you Script47, i was trying to do with rgb looking for amount of blue, but are a lot of blue types than have soft b and high/middle r and g and them i dont know properly how to control it

Answer (score -1):

if anybody wants, i just make a function (80% posibilities to know if rgb color is on blue range). Regards

```
public function is_blue($rgb)
{
    extract($rgb);
    $result = false;

    if(($r<240)&&($g<240)&&($b==255)){ $result = true;}
    if(($r<200)&&($g<200)&&($b>230)){ $result = true;}
    if(($r<175)&&($g<175)&&($b>220)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<150)&&($g<150)&&($b>200)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<125)&&($g<125)&&($b>180)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<100)&&($g<100)&&($b>170)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<80)&&($g<80)&&($b>150)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<60)&&($g<60)&&($b>120)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<40)&&($g<40)&&($b>100)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<20)&&($g<20)&&($b>80)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<10)&&($g<10)&&($b>50)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<10)&&($g<180)&&($b>200)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<10)&&($g<150)&&($b>180)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<10)&&($g<120)&&($b>150)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<10)&&($g<100)&&($b>130)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<10)&&($g<50)&&($b>100)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<10)&&($g<25)&&($b>80)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<80)&&($g<10)&&($b>240)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<60)&&($g<10)&&($b>220)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<40)&&($g<10)&&($b>200)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<20)&&($g<10)&&($b>150)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r==0)&&($g<10)&&($b>50)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<125)&&($g<220)&&($b>200)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<125)&&($g<200)&&($b>220)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<125)&&($g<180)&&($b>180)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<230)&&($g>230)&&($b>240)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<60)&&($g>140)&&($b>160)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<10)&&($g>180)&&($b>200)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<10)&&($g>160)&&($b>180)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<10)&&($g>120)&&($b>160)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<80)&&($g>160)&&($b>180)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<80)&&($b>$g)){ $result = true; }
    if(($r<200)&&($g<200)&&($b>180)){ $result = true; }

    $percent = $r-$g/$g*100;
    if((($percent > -20) or ($percent<20)) and ($b > 200)){$result = true; }

    return $result;
}
```